# Something wrong with my IMAGEVIEW

Tags: android, picasso

I want to build an app contains many things 
but now
I am stuck in my first step which 
wants to implement an activity showing an 
IMAGEVIEW followed by a TEXTVIEW is supposed to appear on the top half of the screenand the TEXTVIEW on the other half. But it acts 
like nothingI wanted it to be.It looks like this:

[image]

The picture is loaded with:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())

            .load(url + "/img/hummingbird-copy.jpg")

            .into(todayImage);
```

I am new to Picasso so I do not know if there are 
something more
I need to do. The text is loaded 
using an AsyncTask. The text loading 
did succeed 
in ScrollView But It appears at somewhere I never 
know in LinearLayout.

The layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/today_image"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />


<TextView

    android:id="@+id/today_text"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

I tried Layout_gravity, Layout_margin*, Layout_padding*, 
and some other
fields, but I haven't found a way to solve 
the problem. The ImageView
always feel scared about the top 
of the screen and the text always 
like playing hide-and-seek.

I guess it is only in three conditions:

1. I did not do well with Picasso.
2. I did not do well with Layout XML.
3. I did not do well in MainActivity.java

and should set something about location of 
ImageView and TextView.

But I do not know which.

Could you please help me?

Comment: man, use a \` signs to wrap things such as `TextView`, `ImageView`

Comment: Give weights to textview and imageview. Wrap_content is not appropriate in this case. Else use RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Saurabh answer is almost correct. The correct XML is:

```
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">


    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/today_image"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sample"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/today_text"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: @Saurabh, only setting height to 0dp garants that weight will be used regardless of the view's content size itself. You can try it yourself, and you'll see what I mean. The imageView should take more than half of parent with your code if the image itself is large enough.

Comment: @Saurabh, sorry, I'm not your dear. If you read my comment and try yourself, you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: lots of functions are there...like resize, fit and scaledown for this

Comment: @VladMatvienko,Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Do like this....

```
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">


    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/today_image"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sample"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/today_text"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

May it help !

Comment: Thanks for your help, but It did not work. My poor computer is driving me crazy.Poor Gradle!

Answer (score 0):

You can set weightSUm on LinearLayout and it can be a value, like 1, and then those 2 views(TextView and ImageView) half of that sum, because are 2 views(1 div 2)

Code should look like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Don't forget to set width and height for both views to match parent.